# Haproxy no detect status mariadb

Tags: centos, mariadb, haproxy

Hello we stuck when connect Haproxy and Mariadb, We have followed [instructions](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-haproxy-as-load-balancer-for-mariadb-on-centos-7/#e-configure-clustercheck) and other instructions from google but Haproxy still has not detected mariadb although is running.

We attach printscreen status **Haproxy** & **xinetd**

[image: HAPROXY Stat]

[image: HAPROXY Status]

[image: xinetd status]

Comment: Let's see the settings for the connection (please mask the password).

Comment: what connection do you mean ?

Comment: this is my config http://imgur.com/a/UKZ5b